# Solve for $x$ when $\sin 2x = \cos x$ where $ x$ is in the domain $ [0, 2\pi]$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Quick question on trig (which I haven't dealt with in a long time):

since $\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x $

$2\sin x\cos x = \cos x$

$2\sin x\cos x/\cos x = 1$

$\sin x = 1/2$

since $\sin x = 1/2$ in quadrants $1$ and $2$, $x = \pi/6$ and $x = 5\pi/6$

Is this correct? If not, hint please.

Comment: An alternate approach would be $\cos x=\sin\bigg(\dfrac\pi2-x\bigg)$ and $\sin x=\sin(2k\pi-x)$, with $k\in$ **Z**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting $$2\sin x\cos x=\cos x,$$
you cannot divide the both sides by $\cos x$ because $\cos x$ can be zero.

So, we have
$$2\sin x\cos x-\cos x=0\iff \cos x(2\sin x-1)=0\iff \cos x=0\ \text{or}\ 2\sin x-1=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Generalized Solution** :

$$\sin ax=\cos bx$$ for example,  $\sin\dfrac{3x}2=\cos5x$ can also be addressed this way

**Method** $\#1:$

$$\cos bx=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-bx\right)\implies\sin ax=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-bx\right)$$

$$\implies ax=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(\frac\pi2-bx\right)$$ where $n$ is any integer

If $n$ is odd, $=2m+1$(say), $ax=(2m+1)\pi-\left(\dfrac\pi2-bx\right)\implies x=\dfrac{(4m+1)\pi}{2(a-b)}$

If $n$ is even, $=2m$(say), $ x=\dfrac{(4m+1)\pi}{2(a+b)}$

Now we need to find the values of $m$ such that $0\le x\le2\pi$

**Method** $\#2:$

$$\sin ax=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-ax\right) \implies\cos bx=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-ax\right)$$

$$\implies bx=2r\pi\pm\left(\frac\pi2-ax\right)$$ where $r$ is any integer

Check for '+', '-' sign one by one

Comment: @FazelN, How about this?